# persistence.xml using java configuration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Why is persistence.xml file needed:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages="es.japanathome")
public class DataAccessConfig
{

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf)
{
    JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
    return txManager;
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory()
{
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(Boolean.TRUE);
    vendorAdapter.setShowSql(Boolean.TRUE);

    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter( vendorAdapter );
    factory.setDataSource( dataSource() );
    factory.setPackagesToScan("es.japanathome.domain");
    factory.setLoadTimeWeaver(new InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver());
    return factory;
}
```

Spring knows where can find my entities, so I don't understand why is still needed this file.

Comment: persistence.xml is used to define the persistence-unit and also the classes that will be used by this persistence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on which Spring version you use, you may not need to provide a persistence.xml.

Since Spring 3.1, [persistence.xml is no longer explicitly](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.1.html#new-in-3.1-jpa-without-xml) required when you're using `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`. Basically `packagesToScan` was added allowing a way for Spring to find @Entity classes.